# C# can't get this simple line of code right

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter");
    * = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("          * * *");
    Console.WriteLine("               ");
    Console.WriteLine("          * * *");
    Console.WriteLine("               ");
    Console.WriteLine("*    *    *   *        *");
    Console.WriteLine("            *        * ");
    Console.WriteLine("*    *    *   *    *  ");
    Console.WriteLine("                       ");
    Console.WriteLine("            *          ");
    Console.WriteLine("                       ");
    Console.WriteLine("          *           ");
    Console.WriteLine("                       ");
    Console.WriteLine("              *");
```

I've been trying to create a sliced cube (with dots from 1-6)
Problem is, it doesn't need to be these "*" I need to do it in any letter someone enters, so I added 2 lines of code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter");
* = Console.ReadLine();"
```

It's been giving an error, so how do I make it work?

**EDIT:** Forgot to include the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1525  Invalid
>   expression term '='   Peot shel kubia shesh besh  D:\Visual Studio
>   Projects\Peot shel kubia shesh besh\Peot shel kubia shesh
>   besh\Program.cs   14

Comment: there is an easier way to do this .. look up the `new string` overload.. for example you can pass any char.. and a size.. also what is the error.? we are not mind readers.. for example if I want to do Console.Write line and I want to print line `*` I would create a variable like this 
`var newDelim = new string('*', 15);` it would add 15 of these `*` before you get to intermediate / more advanced.. start learning how to code first by reading tutorials.. Google is free and there are tons or YouTube free tutorials online

Comment: Youve got a little ways to go here. Learn about variables, assignment, strings, concatenation, and youll see that this is actually a cinch to do.

Comment: You'll want to start with any introductory C# tutorial to see how to create variables.  But as an example, it might look something like: `var userInput = Console.ReadLine();`  Then use the `userInput` variable to build your output.

Comment: C# is not the problem here, your 'simple' line of code is invalid syntax in just about any language you care to name.  You need to do some basic tutorials and learn how C# works.

Answer (score 1):

Basically * means nothing to the compiler. (in the context you have used,  it is a multipler for 2 int/float datatypes.)  You need to make it a variable in this case a string, though it could be any other data type,  something like

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

then in your output you need to reference it.   something like the following

```
Console.WriteLine("          {0} {0} {0}", input);
```

In this you are replaceing the '*' in your code to reference the first `{0}` argument of the call.   if you had multiple arguments,  you could do something like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("          {0} {1} {2}", input, input2, input3);
```

i hope this explains it clearly what your current problem is.   though as many people commented on your post,  this is a fundamental misunderstanding of how to code in C# and i would strongly suggest reading through some basic tutorials,  even flicking through http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/introduction/ would have solved/prevented your issues.

Comment: I misread my question, that's why. I thought I had to print a sliced cube (with the dots etc) in my console, but, it was actually supposed to be a bit more complexed. When I read the question for the second time, I realised I actually had to make the cube of anything the user would type in, like "9" or any other character the user enters.

Comment: Also I didn't really get your answer, could you please explain to me a bit furthur?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how a Sliced Cube looks like. But I am very sure that this is a program which has been given by your teacher or faculty. I am assuming that they might have asked you to print the Sliced Cube with the character input by the user. In this case the code implemented by you is appreciated but wrong.

Firstly you need to take an input from the user. Which could be done from the code below

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Secondly If we need to draw a pattern the approach should not be the repeatation of `Console.WriteLine();` line whereas you should use a loop which will draw this pattern for you. Loops are used do a repetative task. So this might looks like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(userInput);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: I mean like this: http://www.google.co.il/imgres?imgurl=http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/solid/cube.gif&imgrefurl=http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/solid/cube.htm&h=380&w=465&tbnid=API83-PbG0XFsM:&docid=B6Z62dmP1JlxaM&ei=KSwTVqX0KsvTUdDQr5gE&tbm=isch&ved=0CCIQMygHMAdqFQoTCOWs_eTgrMgCFctpFAodUOgLQw                                                                                                                          (With the dots on it from 1-6, with any letter)

Answer (score -1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter");
        string h =  Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("          "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write(" "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write(" "); Console.WriteLine(h);      
        Console.WriteLine("               ");
        Console.Write("          "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write(" "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write(" "); Console.WriteLine(h);
        Console.WriteLine("               ");
        Console.Write(h); Console.Write("    "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write("    "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write("   "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write("        "); Console.WriteLine(h);
        Console.Write("            "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write("        "); Console.WriteLine(h);
        Console.Write(h); Console.Write("    "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write("    "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write("   "); Console.Write(h); Console.Write("    "); Console.WriteLine(h);
        Console.WriteLine(" ");    

        Console.Write("            "); Console.WriteLine(h);
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.Write("          "); Console.WriteLine(h);
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.Write("              "); Console.WriteLine(h);
```

After about an hour of coding, I re-coded the whole program and now it's okay. I get the cube no matter what letter I type in  :D
But thanks to all those who replied and helped me.

Comment: I'm glad you found something that worked,  but if this is for an assignment (and it sounds like it is)  you will get very low marks for that solution.   it is about the ugliest solution you could possibly come up with.